# Как обратится к строковому ресурсу с составным именем, через цикл for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеются строки с названиями формата `String1`, `String2`, `String3` и т.д.
Дальнейшая работа с ними идет в цикле for. Как я могу обратиться к какой-либо из этих строк через цикл?

**Пример:**

```
String1 = 'Текст первой строки'
String2 = 'Текст второй строки'
String3 = 'Текст третей строки'
String4 = 'Текст четвертой строки'
String5 = 'Текст пятой строки'

for i in range(1,6):
   print(f'String{i}')
```

**Текущий вывод:**

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
```

**Требуемый результат:**

```
Текст первой строки
Текст второй строки
Текст третей строки
Текст четвертой строки
Текст пятой строки
```

Comment: Использовать список вместо отдельных переменных. Как только у переменных появляются порядковые номера - это сразу сигнал... эээ... низкокачественного кода.

Comment: Понял. Перенесу в массив, чтобы обращаться по номерам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(globals()[f"String{i}"])
```

Comment: Форматированием строки, в предыдущем примере была конкатенация строк :)

Comment: Я через f-строки тоже сначала хотел, но не сумел. Оказывается, таки можно было )

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так, если очень хочется:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(globals()["String"+str(i)])
```

Но лучше так не делать, конечно, а завести для однотипных объектов массив, как правильно указали в комментариях.