# Как можно минимизировать повторение кода при выполнении идентичных действий несколько раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, например:

```
def products(text):
    text = text.split()
    print(text)
    f1 = open("products/Сервер.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    soft1 = f1.read().split()
    print(soft1)
    f1.close()
    f2 = open("products/З.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    soft2 = f2.read().split()
    print(soft2)
    f2.close()
    f3 = open("products/Зуб.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    soft3 = f3.read().split()
    print(soft3)
    f3.close()
    f4 = open("products/Health.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    soft4 = f4.read().split()
    print(soft4)
    f4.close()
    text = [i.lower() for i in text]
    soft1 = [i.lower() for i in soft1]
    soft2 = [i.lower() for i in soft2]
    soft3 = [i.lower() for i in soft3]
    soft4 = [i.lower() for i in soft4]
    print(text)
    print(soft1, soft2, soft3, soft4)
    x1 = list(set(text) & set(soft1))
    x2 = list(set(text) & set(soft2))
    x3 = list(set(text) & set(soft3))
    x4 = list(set(text) & set(soft4))
    print(x1)
    print(x2)
    print(x3)
    print(x4)
    x1 = len(x1)
    x2 = len(x2)
    x3 = len(x3)
    x4 = len(x4)
    print(x1, x2, x3, x4)
    x = max(x1, x2, x3, x4)
    print(x)
    if x1 == x2 == x3 == x4:
        print('Сформулюйте будь ласка більш чітко питання!')
        from sys import exit
        exit()
    if x == x1:
        print(f1)
    if x == x2:
        print(f2)
    if x == x3:
        print(f3)
    if x == x4:
        print(f4)
```

Можно ли как-то через **цикл for** менять просто цифру после f? Я так понимаю таким образом (псевдокод):

```
i = 1
for i in f:
     f[i] = open()
     i++
```

Таким образом возможно решить проблему повторения кода?

Comment: Я сам недавно задавал подобный вопрос. Вроде как вам это должно помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192698/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%83-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for

Comment: А когда вы пишите for i in f, что у вас записано в f, вы понимаете?

Comment: Вот тут я немножко и теряюсь, как вписать индекс в заголовок цикла, либо range через len?

Answer (score 4):

чем вас не устраивает запись в массив и работа с массивом?

```
soft = []
f1 = open("products/Сервер.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
soft.append(f1.read().split())
f1.close()
f2 = open("products/З.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
soft.append(f1.read().split())
f2.close()

for text in soft:
    print(text)
```

даже считывать файлы можно в цикле

```
pathes = ["products/Сервер.txt", "products/З.txt"]

soft = []
for path in pathes:
    f = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    soft.append(f.read().split())
    f.close()

for text in soft:
    print(text)
```

Например весь код можно свернуть вот так:

```
def products(text):
    text = text.lower().split()

    soft = []

    pathes = ["products/Сервер.txt", "products/З.txt", "products/Зуб.txt", "products/Health.txt"]

    for path in pathes:
        f = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        soft.append({'path': path, 'len': len(list(set(text) & set(f.read().lower().split())))})
        f.close()

    x_max = max(map(lambda obj: obj['len'], soft))

    isEqual = True
    for i in range(1, len(soft)):
        if soft[i]['len'] != soft[i - 1]['len']:
            isEqual = False
            break

    if isEqual:
        print('Сформулюйте будь ласка більш чітко питання!')
        from sys import exit
        exit()

    for obj in soft:
        if obj['len'] == x_max:
            print(obj['path'])
```

вместо

```
isEqual = True
for i in range(1, len(soft)):
    if soft[i]['len'] != soft[i - 1]['len']:
        isEqual = False
        break
```

можно сделать так:

```
isEqual = all([obj['len'] == x_max for obj in soft])
```

Comment: Мне нужно значение введённое с клавиатуры, проверить с содержимым 3 файлов.

Comment: Благодарю, как-то и не подумал что файлы можно по "индексно" пропустить через цикл !!!

Comment: @Miklós Oláh, добавил весь ваш код сформированный по такому принципу (возможно чуть допилить надо)

Comment: Благодарю!!! Не ожидал такой помощи...

Answer (score 2):

Можно через цикл как ты указал, а можно через ООП - создать класс и описать в нем нужный тебе метод, далее выполнять все действия через его экземпляры. Но способ с ООП больше подходит когда программа большая и в ней часто приходится повторять одни и теже действия по много раз - в таком случае ООП заметно облегчит задачу, но если это какой-то частный случай (будкт использован единично) и необходимости его дальнейшего использования не предвидится - лучше цикл.

Comment: Ага, благодарю. Сделаю цикл. Но теперь план на ноябрь - разобраться как это сделать через ООП )))

Comment: https://torlook.info/python.+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE+2019 вот тут торрент с видеокурсом, очень доходчиво объясняет автор